# How to do with the unbalanced dataset for multi label with bertforsequenceclassification?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, multilabel-classification

I have a BERT model of multi label classification with bertforsequenceclassification, and the dataset is highly unbalanced with 15 classes, as you see here is the pos_weights:

tensor([ 86.5999,   3.3153,   0.8365,   6.6842,  86.5999,   7.0367,   3.3582,
144.9998,  11.5143,  27.2581,  11.0000,  21.4615,  38.8182,   2.7597,
174.1996])

I feed this in the loss function torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(), however, most of the result turns out to 0 because when I apply sigmoid and make a threshold 0.5 to determine the value, most of them are close to 0.5 but still under 0.5. so I'm not sure if I handle the unbalanced data well,  or probably having other problems, also, when I tried to improve it, I actually don't know if I can simply set 0.5 as the threshold to this unbalanced case.

Did I miss any part of it? or what should I add if I want to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Comment: oops Im sorry didn't aware this, thanks!